# redirect HTACCESS

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I have a problem with redirect 301 write with htaccess.

I added the followind text to my htaccess.txt but it doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#  mod_rewrite in use
RewriteEngine On
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://www.old_site.com/en/about-us/company-profile.html http://www.new_site.com/en/about-us/company-profile.html
```

I also tried the following without success:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#  mod_rewrite in use
RewriteEngine On
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 /en/about-us/company-profile.html http://www.new_site.com/en/about-us/company-profile.html
```

Where is the error?
Do I make changes in robots.txt?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of file from `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`. **STRICTLY** speaking, the extension of the file is `.htaccess` and there is no name prefixed to it.